# Как передать параметры в paramMap?

Tags: java, map

мне надо сделать так, чтобы paramMap использовал параметры Date oD, Date dO. Как я мог бы это сделать

```
    public List<OdchylenieStandDTO> odchylenie(Date oD, Date dO) {
        final String sql = "select sample, round(avg(czas),0) as srednia, round(stddev(czas),0) as stdev" +
                "from jmeter_results" +
                "where ttimestamp <= (current_timestamp - interval '1 week')" +
                "group by sample";

        final Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
        final List<OdchylenieStandDTO> listaWynikowodchylenia = this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate
                .query(sql, paramMap, (final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) -> new OdchylenieStandDTO(
                        rs.getString("sample"),
                        rs.getBigDecimal("srednia"),
                        rs.getBigDecimal("stdev")
                ));

        return listaWynikowodchylenia;
    }
```

Пока что эти параметры не будут использоваться, пока я не изменю команду SQL и возможно что-то под paramMap

Comment: *paramMap использовал параметры Date oD*, уточните, в каком виде использовал и какие параметры?

Comment: @azlov параметры: oD, dO;
Нужно чтобы odchylenie передал свои параметры paramMap

Comment: `paramMap.put(*key*, oD);  // положить в paramMap oD` ?

Comment: @azlov после этого перестало работать .query(...
то есть теперь подчеркивается красной линией

Comment: Если вы хотите хранить `Date`  в `paramMap`, то так и указывайте `final Map<String, Date> paramMap = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: ну я так сделал сразу после вашего ответа с .put(), ну и собсвтенно ошибка так и осталась